# How can I find the distance of each pixel in the boundary image to the centre of the image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I found the centre of the mass of an object in MATLAB:

```
props= regionprops(image, 'centroid');
```

I have also found the boundary of the mass. How can I find distance of each pixel in the boundary image to the centre of the image?

Comment: Need more information.  How is your boundary stored?  Is it stored as an image or as an array of points?

Comment: What is a *boundary image*?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what format you have your boundary stored.   There are two possible scenarios to your question which depend on how the boundary is stored:

1. If the boundary is stored as an image
2. If the boundary is stored as a 2D array of points

Let's tackle each scenario one at a time.  I'm going to assume that your image boundary and original image are both **binary**, as that is what `regionprops` takes in as input.

## Boundary as an image

Simply extract the row and column coordinates from the boundary image, then find the Euclidean distance between the centre coordinate and each point along the boundary.  Assuming your image boundary is stored in `B`, you would simply do this:

```
centre = props.Centroid;
[rows, cols] = find(B);
dists = sqrt((rows-centre(2)).^2 + (cols-centre(1)).^2);
```

`rows` and `cols` would contain the row and column locations of each contour point along the boundary.  `dists` would contain the distances between each of the contour points, stored in `rows` and `cols`, with respect to the centre.  Also remember that the `Centroid` property of `regionprops` stores the centre of mass such that the first element is the `x` or **column** coordinate while the second element is the `y` or **row** coordinate.

## Boundary as an array of 2D points

Assuming that your points are stored in a 2D array where the first column denotes the **row** coordinate and the second column denotes the **column** coordinate and the array is called `points`, this would simply become:

```
centre = props.Centroid;
dists = sqrt((points(:,1)-centre(2)).^2 + (points(:,2)-centre(1)).^2);
```

`dists` is the same array as seen in the first scenario.

Comment: my boundry is as an image(b)

Comment: my image is in a .I wrote like this:props=regionprops(a,'centroid');
centre = props.Centroid;
[rows, cols] = find(b);
dists = sqrt((rows-centre.Centroid(2)).^2 + (cols-centre.Centroid(1)).^2);

Comment: but it gives error:                                                                                Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.

Comment: Try it now. Made a mistake. Oops! I edited my post. Check the edits

Comment: Accept my answer if I have helped. Click on the checkmark underneath the up and down arrows at the top of my post to the left.